SharePoint Classic - JavaScript issue
This is my JavaScript file that works, but only does not work in SharePoint. May I please have assistance on why it doesnt?
function initializeCustomScript() {
    // Wait for the DOM to fully load before setting up event handlers
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        setupEventHandlers();
    });
}

function setupEventHandlers() {
    // Query all items for which you want to set up click handlers
    const boxgridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".boxgrid__item");
    
    // Data structure to hold item information
    const itemData = {
        // Add your item data here, using a generic format
    };

    // Array to keep track of selected items for display
    const selectedItemDetails = [];

    // Set up click event listeners for each item
    boxgridItems.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
            const itemName = item.querySelector("span").textContent.trim();

            if (itemData[itemName]) {
                const itemImages = itemData[itemName].images;
                const itemDescription = itemData[itemName].description || "No description available.";

                selectedItemDetails.push({ itemName, itemImages, itemDescription });
                updateItemDetails(selectedItemDetails);
            } else {
                console.error("Error: Item data not found.");
            }
        });
    });

    function updateItemDetails(details) {
        // Clear existing details
        const itemDetailsImages = document.querySelector(".item-details__images");
        const itemDetailsContent = document.querySelector(".item-details__content");

        itemDetailsImages.innerHTML = '';
        itemDetailsContent.innerHTML = '';

        // Update details section with selected item information
        details.forEach((itemDetail) => {
            const { itemName, itemImages, itemDescription } = itemDetail;

            itemImages.forEach((imageUrl, index) => {
                const imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
                imgContainer.classList.add("item-details__image-container");

                const img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = imageUrl;
                img.alt = itemName + " Image " + (index + 1);

                const imgWrapper = document.createElement("div");
                imgWrapper.classList.add("item-details__image-wrapper");

                const imgTitle = document.createElement("h3");
                imgTitle.classList.add("item-details__image-title");
                imgTitle.textContent = itemName + " Image " + (index + 1);

                const imgDescription = document.createElement("p");
                imgDescription.classList.add("item-details__image-description");
                imgDescription.textContent = "Image " + (index + 1) + " description.";

                const imgLink = document.createElement("a");
                imgLink.classList.add("item-details__image-link");
                imgLink.href = imageUrl;
                imgLink.textContent = "View Image";

                imgWrapper.appendChild(img);
                imgWrapper.appendChild(imgTitle);
                imgWrapper.appendChild(imgDescription);
                imgWrapper.appendChild(imgLink);

                imgContainer.appendChild(imgWrapper);
                itemDetailsImages.appendChild(imgContainer);
            });

            const descriptionContainer = document.createElement("div");
            descriptionContainer.classList.add("item-details__description");
            descriptionContainer.textContent = itemDescription;

            itemDetailsContent.appendChild(descriptionContainer);
        });

        document.querySelector(".item-details").classList.add("show");
    }
}

